# Select XML tags that have certain tags inside them

Tags: python, xml, tags

I am parsing an xml file with Python using ElementTree, and I need to select tags like `<PostalAddressText>` below that have tags like `<insert>` inside them. How do I do that? I need to get a list of all relevant tag names in the xml file that satisfy the condition.

Here's a fragment of XML that I am parsing (the actual text except for inside tags has been replaced with *Lorem Ipsum*):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <PostalAddressText>123456,
    <insert>
</insert>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <insert>
</insert>consectetur adipiscing elit.<insert>
</insert>Etiam cursus ligula non malesuada fringilla.<delete> </delete><insert>
</insert>Quisque porta quam eu finibus pulvinar.<delete>or</delete><insert>er</insert> Mauris at semper urna.<delete>a</delete><insert>o</insert> Donec feugiat<delete>arcu purus</delete><insert>et lacinia</insert></PostalAddressText>
    <PersonNameText>789012,
    <insert>
</insert>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <insert>
</insert>consectetur adipiscing elit.<insert>
</insert>Etiam cursus ligula non malesuada fringilla.<delete> </delete><insert>
</insert>Quisque porta quam eu finibus pulvinar.<delete>or</delete><insert>er</insert> Mauris at semper urna.<delete>a</delete><insert>o</insert> Donec feugiat<delete>arcu purus</delete><insert>et lacinia</insert>
    </PersonNameText>
</data>
```

I have tried this but nothing gets printed to the console:

```
test_data = root.findall(".//")
for el in test_data:
    if el.text == '*<insert>*':
        print(el.tag, el.text)
```

Comment: Can `</diff:insert>` bu only under  `<com:PostalAddressText`?

Comment: @balderman no, there may be different tags with <diff:insert> under them. I only need to find all tags that have <diff:insert> "inside" them

Comment: Post a VALID xml please. Make sure a parser can parse it.

Comment: @balderman I've now changed the xml example, it gets parsed OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is your expected output but see the code and output below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <PostalAddressText>123456,
    <insert>
</insert>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <insert>
</insert>consectetur adipiscing elit.<insert>
</insert>Etiam cursus ligula non malesuada fringilla.<delete> </delete><insert>
</insert>Quisque porta quam eu finibus pulvinar.<delete>or</delete><insert>er</insert> Mauris at semper urna.<delete>a</delete><insert>o</insert> Donec feugiat<delete>arcu purus</delete><insert>et lacinia</insert></PostalAddressText>
    <PersonNameText>789012,
    <insert>
</insert>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <insert>
</insert>consectetur adipiscing elit.<insert>
</insert>Etiam cursus ligula non malesuada fringilla.<delete> </delete><insert>
</insert>Quisque porta quam eu finibus pulvinar.<delete>or</delete><insert>er</insert> Mauris at semper urna.<delete>a</delete><insert>o</insert> Donec feugiat<delete>arcu purus</delete><insert>et lacinia</insert>
    </PersonNameText>
</data>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for idx, insert in enumerate(root.findall('.//insert'), 1):
    print(f'{idx}) {insert.text}  {insert.tail}')
```

output

```
1) 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
2) 
  consectetur adipiscing elit.
3) 
  Etiam cursus ligula non malesuada fringilla.
4) 
  Quisque porta quam eu finibus pulvinar.
5) er   Mauris at semper urna.
6) o   Donec feugiat
7) et lacinia  None
8) 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
9) 
  consectetur adipiscing elit.
10) 
  Etiam cursus ligula non malesuada fringilla.
11) 
  Quisque porta quam eu finibus pulvinar.
12) er   Mauris at semper urna.
13) o   Donec feugiat
14) et lacinia
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need something a bit different. I need to get a list of tag names that satisfy condition _"contains <insert> tag inside"_. If we take example xml above, the list would be:

`PostalAddressText,
PersonNameText`

Comment: I've used your code to come up with solution to my problem, thanks!

Comment: Glad I managed to help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result that I needed with the following code (I got the idea from @balderman):

```
for el in root.findall('.//*[insert]'): 
    print(el.tag)
```

Which gave me the name of the tag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).